# How to Parse an string which is in format of : String jsonResponce = [SELECT id, Name,AccountNumber, Industry from Account LIMIT 10 ].toString();

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, developer

So my requirement is, I should consider the

```java
USER_DEBUG [17]|DEBUG|jsonResponce==(Account:{Id=0015i00000A0K04AAF, Name=GenePoint, AccountNumber=CC978213, Industry=Biotechnology}, Account:{Id=0015i00000A0K02AAF, Name=United Oil & Gas, UK, AccountNumber=CD355119-A, Industry=Energy}, Account:{Id=0015i00000A0K03AAF, Name=United Oil & Gas, Singapore, AccountNumber=CD355120-B, Industry=Energy}, Account:{Id=0015i00000A0JzuAAF, Name=Edge Communications, AccountNumber=CD451796, Industry=Electronics}
```

as an JSON Response and based on the AccountNumber, I should Insert if duplicates found i need to update

### Here is my code:

```java
public class AnimalsCallouts {  
    public List<Account>Account;   
    public class AnimalsNum{
        public Integer AccountNumber;
        public Integer Id;
        public string Name;
    } 
    public static HttpResponse makeGetCallout() {
        
        integer count = 1;
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals');
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
        if(response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // Deserializes the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.        
            String jsonResponce = [SELECT id, Name,AccountNumber, Industry from Account LIMIT 10 ].toString();
            /*              {
                             "Account": [
                                          {
                                             "Id": "0015i00000A0K04AAF",
                                             "Name": "GenePoint",
                                             "AccountNumber": "CC978213"
                                             }
                                         ]
                                        }
            */
            system.debug('jsonResponce=='+jsonResponce);
            JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonResponce);
            system.debug('parser=='+parser);
            //  List<String> deserializedresponse = (List<String>)JSON.deserialize(jsonResponce, List<String>.class);
            List<Account> acc =  new List<Account>();   
            Map<String,Account> existingrecmap = new Map<String,Account>();        
            
            // upsert acc;           
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Your jsonResponce variable is just the very not-JSON-encoded System.debug string of a list of records. You need to actually parse the data from response.getBody(), then match up those values with existing values. However, the resource quoted only gives a list of animals, not a list of accounts, so we can't provide you with a concrete answer. What are you actually trying to do, and how can we help?

Answer (score -1):

There is an online tool to do this. You can check https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/json2apex. I think this will help you.

Thanks!